# How to convert datesrting to short date object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to UI (User Interface) coding and I have date from `json` as **"2021-02-28 00:00:00"**. But while writing to the xlsx I don't want the date in string form. And this is what I have tried.

```
variable = new Date("2021-02-28 00:00:00")
```

Which give the date object as below

```
Sun Feb 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

But I want the date to be in below format [should be still a date object not a string]

```
28 Feb 2021 00:00:00
```

Comment: "But i want the date to be in below format [should be still a date object not a string]" - I think you don't understand how dates are represented inside computers.

Comment: @AlonEitan the thing if i format the date the typeof the date converts to string. And i am looking for a sloution to keep the typeof date as object so that after writing into the xlsx file user can filter the dates

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using Date object but there's many lines to do that.

I handle all my date formatting with moment.

e.g.
moment('2021-02-28 00:00:00').format('DD MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss')

```js
console.log(moment('2021-02-28 00:00:00').format('DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```